# Onboarding for Yodlee REST API

Tags: yodlee

We're a Yodlee incubator company and we're starting to look at the Yodlee integration.  Specifically, we are interested in the REST API.

We have a login for http://developers.yodlee.com/.  However, the documentation seems to be focused around the SOAP API and the sample app used a Java SDK Client that only works with version 9 (we're on 11).  reports5.yodlee.com/yodleedocuments/sdkEE11.1/ seems to only have the SOAP documentation and the deprecated Java SDK as well.  Finally, we have logins for http://forum.yodlee.com/, and it seems to refer to an address 64.14.28.78, but I'm still not clear on where to start.

We're hoping to get help with the onboarding process.  We already have a cobrand and password, we're just not sure where to go from here as we can't find any REST API documentation.  Any help be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Currently Yodlee supports only few calls over REST APIs.
You can refer to the document at
https://reports5.yodlee.com/yodleedocuments/sdkEE11.1/Aggregation/Aggregation Quick Reference Guide-11.1.pdf

This document has a section called REST and you will find all the details in that document about using Yodlee's REST APIs.

Comment: Well I am also trying to get onboard with Yodlee and I am using the sample apps, I tried to follow the link supplied above but its behind a username and password. I entered my coBrand username and password but that didnt work. So not very helpful.

Comment: The REST service for yodlee is a joke and doesnt follow any rest guidelines at all.

Answer (score 3):

Yodlee just recently released their full REST API (I think a day or two ago) it is pretty well documented now (https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference).

If you haven't look into it since their "full" release you should give it a shot, I am working my way through it currently and it seems that they have done a fairly good job.

Comment: IAV REST API is also available at https://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification(IAV)_API/IAV_Services_Guide/API_References/IAV_REST_API_Reference

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee published new API (looks like follow REST guidelines).
I think it is from 2016 April.
https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API
Documentation: https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php
sample applications: https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Sample_Applications

Good Lock